# How to mae Traefik as reverse-proxy with docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I have docker-compose build with symfony on apache and angular on nginx. It is possible that more docker-compositions can be run, so now I want to make my own DNS using traefik - I want to set hostname of each app, make docker-compose up and resolve apps with hostname when they are ready.

Traefik docker-compose:

```
version: '3.1'

networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
  internal:
    external: false

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.1
    command: --api.insecure=true --providers.docker
    labels:
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:monitor.docker.localhost
      - traefik.port=8080
    networks:
      - proxy
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Apps docker-compose:

```
# Run docker-compose build
# Run docker-compose up
# Live long and prosper

version: '3.1'
networks:
  proxy:
   external: true
  internal:
   external: false
services:
    apache:
        build: .docker/apache
        container_name: sf4_apache
        volumes:
          - .docker/config/vhosts:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
          - ./backend:/home/wwwroot/sf4
        depends_on:
          - php
        labels:
          - traefik.http.routers.sf4_apache.rule=Host(`symfony.docker.localhost`)
          - traefik.http.services.apache.loadbalancer.server.port=80
        networks:
         - internal
         - proxy   

    php:
        build: .docker/php
        container_name: sf4_php
        volumes:
          - ./backend:/home/wwwroot/sf4
          - ./executor:/home/wwwroot/pipe
        networks:
         - internal
        labels:
         - traefik.enable=false  


    nginx:
      container_name: angular_nginx
      build: .docker/nginx
      volumes:
        - ./frontend/dist/frontend:/usr/share/nginx/html
      ports:
        - "81:80"
        - "443:443"
      labels:
        - traefik.http.routers.angular_nginx.rule=Host(`angular.docker.localhost`)
      networks:
        - internal
        - proxy     
    node:
        build: .docker/node
        container_name: angular_node
        ports:
            - 4200:4200
        volumes:
            - ./frontend:/home/node/app/frontend
        tty: true
        command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - |
                cd /home/node/app/frontend && npm start
        expose:
            - "4200"   
        networks:
         - internal
        labels:
         - traefik.enable=false
```

Can't make it work: sometimes I get Bad Gateway at domains (symfony.docker.localhost), sometimes it crushed because both servers using one port, so please help me to run this correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, docker frontend and backend are deprecated in version 2.1 check this [link](https://docs.traefik.io/migration/v1-to-v2/)

here is an example of doing the same in traefik 2.1

```
version: '3.7'

networks:
  traefik:
    external: true

volumes:
  db_data:

services:

  proxy:
    image: traefik:v2.1
    command:
      - '--providers.docker=true'
      - '--entryPoints.web.address=:80'
      - '--providers.providersThrottleDuration=2s'
      - '--providers.docker.watch=true'
      - '--providers.docker.swarmMode=true'
      - '--providers.docker.swarmModeRefreshSeconds=15s'
      - '--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false'
      - '--providers.docker.defaultRule=Host("local.me")'
      - '--accessLog.bufferingSize=0'
      - '--api=true'
      - '--api.dashboard=true'
      - '--api.insecure=true'
      - '--ping.entryPoint=web'
    volumes:
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro'
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '8080:8080'
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
      update_config:
        delay: 10s
        order: start-first
        parallelism: 1
      rollback_config:
        parallelism: 0
        order: stop-first
    logging:
      driver: json-file
      options:
        'max-size': '10m'
        'max-file': '5'
    networks:
      - traefik

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: mysqld --general-log=1 --general-log-file=/var/log/mysql/general-log.log
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
      update_config:
        delay: 10s
        order: start-first
        parallelism: 1
      rollback_config:
        parallelism: 0
        order: stop-first
    logging:
      driver: json-file
      options:
        'max-size': '10m'
        'max-file': '5'
    networks:
      - traefik
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: dummy
      MYSQL_DATABASE: rails_blog_production

  rails_blog_web:
    image: wshihadeh/rails_blog:demo-v1
    command: 'web'
    deploy:
      labels:
        - traefik.enable=true
        - traefik.http.services.blog.loadbalancer.server.port=8080
        - traefik.http.routers.blog.rule=Host(`blog.local.me`)
        - traefik.http.routers.blog.service=blog
        - traefik.http.routers.blog.entrypoints=web
        - traefik.docker.network=traefik
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 120s
      update_config:
        delay: 10s
        order: start-first
        parallelism: 1
      rollback_config:
        parallelism: 0
        order: stop-first
    logging:
      driver: json-file
      options:
        'max-size': '10m'
        'max-file': '5'
    networks:
      - traefik
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: mysql2://root:dummy@mysql/rails_blog_production
      RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES: 'true'
```

for more information, you can check this [blog post](https://medium.com/better-programming/traefik-2-1-as-a-reverse-proxy-c9e274da0a32)

Comment: You have only 1 docker-compose, but I need to use traefik with several. And no docker-swarm

Comment: you can split this into three files, each of the service in its own that is not an issue. you only need to make sure that all service keep using the same network

Comment: I have nginx and apache both using 80 port inside conatiners, can it cause a problem?

Comment: no that is ok, as long as you don't expose the same port twice to the external host (you don't need to expose it)

Comment: Working! Thanks great for help